# What is the best method to manipulate xml files?

Tags: c#, regex, xpath, xsd, linq-to-xml

I want to manipulate XML files.

```
...
<Document Id="1091">
      <Indexes>
        <Index Name="MODD" Value="aaa" />
        <Index Name="DDAT" Value="bbb" />
        <Index Name="CDAT" Value="ccc" />
        <Index Name="MDAT" Value="ddd" />
        <Index Name="DOCN" Value="eee" />
        <Index Name="STAT" Value="fff" />
        ...
      </Indexes>
</Document>
<Document Id="2088">
      ...
```

I have retrieve the value of some index randomly. I would avoid the loop on all the indexes. What is the tool you advise me to use and why?

- load the file as a text file and use RegEx
- load the xml file and use XPath
- load the xml file and use Linq to Xml
- generate the classes with xsd.exe or xsd2code
- another approach

Comment: However you do it, **don't use regex.**

Comment: And I'd try Linq to Xml first. I find it superior for most scenarios.

Comment: Never use any form of string manipulation on XML files. Different set of rules.

Comment: without complete use case, this is subjective (By now, you have _"Good syntax and easy to use!"_ and _"is awesome!"_ kind of answers and comments...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with LinqToXml. Good syntax and easy to use!